# Can I add a timer to my view to segue to next view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I have a view and the user is in this view, and there is no way to go away. There is an ad, and than after a period of time the "go" button appears, or better, it goes to next view automatically! I'm using a storyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to do it in code. It's as simple as:

```
- (void)goToNextView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToNextView" sender:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSelector:@selector(goToNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

Now `segueToNextView` will happen 5 seconds after the view controller loads.

Answer (score 1):

certainly, add the timer, and then in the timer handler, call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` .  you'll have to do this in code; you'll get the name of the segue as you set it in the storyboard, and then use that as the identifier argument to the call.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: self)
}
```